# Device based access policy for Laravel

Tags: laravel, security, authentication, device

Security is not my area of expertise. I am working on a lightweight administrative `Laravel` web app for internal use by company (small) employees:

- The app is intended to be used only by the employees
- Remote work (from home) is not uncommon
- Smartphones and laptops are usually used when working remotely

I would like to secure it as much as possible - beyond authentication, access controls or 2FA. I am trying to think of ways to make it virtually invisible to the public, but still available for the employees. Defining proper rules for crawlers might make it a bit more obscure but I think more could be done. Network based restrictions would limit the employee flexibility.

Based on this I got the idea that the app could be made available only if the  request is made by an authorized device. I am not sure however whether or not this is a good approach. Neither do I know how to tackle the problem of authorizing the various devices and making that information available to the server during communication.

i.e. *How would I tag a device as authorized so that I only have to do it once and can reliably validate the information in a web app?* Regular authentication as well as role based access would still be in place but the app could return a 404 response if the accessing device is not whitelisted.

Is there a way to achieve something like this while not making it too restrictive for the users or painful to set up? Or is there a better method for achieving the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consider a VPN?**

If you are hosting the device on an internal network, you could see if the IT dept. can set up VPN access to work remotely (in most cases, this is already in place) and then it does not need to be accessed over the internet via a URI. Instead you can simply navigate to the internal address once you're in the network through the VPN - no public access and no need to worry about pesky web crawlers!

It also makes it easier to moderate your application. For example, if an employee leaves the company you can simply revoke their VPN access and they'll no longer be able to access the application.